# stdin redirection for the script that asks for the input

Tags: io-redirection, stdin

I'm trying to get the script that asks for the input to work when stdin is redirected. It could be that this is not even possible, but I would like to understand why.  Here is an example:

```
$ echo 'q = raw_input("question ?"); print "\ngot: ", q' | python -  < <(echo answer)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'answer' is not defined
```

I know I can get it to work with this:

```
$ python <(echo 'q = raw_input("question ?"); print "\ngot: ", q') < <(echo answer)
question ?
got:  answer
```

but this is a process substitution.  Is it possible to get it to work only with redirection?

Comment: I'm not sure I get the main point here, is there some reason to not use `python -c` or a program saved in a file? Or does your script need to read something from stdin and prompt the user at the same time? Which would lead to the usual idea of giving the input from a file named at the script command line. Is there some reason you don't want that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, maybe. One way is to open up the TTY and interact with that:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
package require Tcl 8.5

gets stdin line; puts "stdin: $line"

set tty [open /dev/tty r+]
chan configure $tty -buffering none

puts -nonewline $tty "nimi sina li seme? "
set name [gets $tty]

gets stdin line; puts "stdin: $line"
puts $tty "name: $name"
```

Which has results thusly given the above saved in `./prompt`, `chmod +x`, installed `expect`, etc.

```
$ (echo foo; echo bar) | ./prompt
stdin: foo
nimi sina li seme? Bob
stdin: bar
name: Bob
$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo 'q = ...' | python -  < <(echo answer)
```

This isn't going to work since you're redirecting to python's stdin twice. The (later) redirection of `< <(echo answer)` takes effect, and python gets only the word `answer` as the script to run.

Opening `/dev/tty` (or even `/dev/stderr`) can work even if stdin is redirected.

```
$ echo foo | python -c 'import sys; 
     s = sys.stdin.readline(); 
     print "from stdin:", s; 
     t = open("/dev/tty", "r"); 
     s = t.readline(); 
     print "from tty:", s;'
```

Of course this requires that the script is running with a tty, and not from cron or similar.